# How do I send a sticker in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I can't figure out how to send a sticker in discord.js. Here is my code (ids removed):

```js
let reply = {
     content: `hello world`,
     stickers: client.guilds.cache.get('guild id').stickers.fetch('sticker id')
}
msg.reply(reply)
```

And when trying that I get this error:

```js
sticker_ids: this.options.stickers?.map(sticker => sticker.id ?? sticker),
                                    ^

TypeError: this.options.stickers?.map is not a function
```

But if I just try `stickers: client.guilds.cache.get('guild id').stickers.cache` it works but instead sends every sticker in the server

Does anyone know what this error means, how to fix it, and if there is just a better way of doing all this? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know how stickers work at all so I'm just going off the error message, but it looks like stickers still needs to be a `Collection` so try `stickers: client.guilds.cache.get("guild id").stickers.cache.filter(s => s.id === "sticker id")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@isaac.g](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16158590/isaac-g) [said:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73668931/how-do-i-send-a-sticker-in-discord-js#comment130090921_73668931)

> it looks like stickers still needs to be a `Collection` so try `stickers: client.guilds.cache.get("guild id").stickers.cache.filter(s => s.id === "sticker id")`

And that worked fine for me.